# Is there a way to integrate Mapbox Search UI SDK and Maps SDK in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have tried creating them both seperately as UIViewControllerRepresentables and using a ZStack but that results in the Mapview not being active. This is how mapbox did it with [UIKit](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/search/examples/search-ui-and-maps-sdk/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to wrap entire `SimpleUISearchViewController` from the example into `UIViewControllerRepresentable` ?